# Symfony2 custom form type key pair

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3, fosrestbundle

I'm currently trying to implement a key-pair value for a form type, which is used together with the FOSRestBundle to allow for sending a request like the following:

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "some_user",
        "custom_fields": {
            "telephone": "07777",
            "other_custom_field": "other custom value"
        }
    }
}
```

The backend for this is represented as follows:

> *User*
>
> id, username, customFields
>
> *CustomUserField*
>
> id, field
>
> *CustomUserFieldValue*
>
> user_id, field_id, value

I've currently made a custom form as follows:

```
<?php

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('username')
            ->add(
                'custom_fields',
                'user_custom_fields_type'
            )
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class'      => 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\User',
                'csrf_protection' => false,
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

And my `user_custom_fields_type`:

```
<?php

class CustomUserFieldType extends AbstractType
{
    private $em;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $fields = $this->em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:CustomUserField')->findAll();

        foreach($fields as $field) {
            $builder->add($field->getField(), 'textarea');
        }
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'invalid_message' => 'The selected custom field does not exist'
            )
        );
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'collection';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_custom_fields_type';
    }
}
```

This keeps giving me the error that there are extra fields. Which are the ones I've added in the `CustomUserFieldType`. How can I get this working?

Note: this is a simplified version of the actual code, I've tried removing all the irrelevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use form listeners to add dynamic fields to your forms: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

In your case a `PRE_SET_DATA` should suffice. Something like this:

```
$em = $this->em;

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
function (FormEvent $event) use ( $em )
{
    // get the form
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // fetch your data here
    $fields = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:CustomUserField')->findAll();

    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        // make sure you add the new fields to $form and not $builder from this event
        $form->add($field->getField(), 'textarea');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and finally solved it by parsing the custom fields manually. If there is another solution, please share :)

In the UserType form:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ( $oEm, $oUser )
        {
            $oForm = $event->getForm();
            $aFields = $oEm->getRepository('MyDBBundle:CustomUserField')->findAll();

            /** @var CustomUserField $oField */
            foreach($aFields as $oField)
            {
                $oForm->add(
                    'custom__'.$oField->getKey(),
                    $oField->getType(),
                    array(
                        'label'     => $oField->getField(),
                        'mapped'    => false,
                        'required'  => false
                    )
                );
                /** @var CustomUserFieldValue $oFieldValue */
                $oFieldValue = $oEm->getRepository('MyDBBundle:CustomUserFieldValue')->findOneBy(array('user' => $oUser, 'field' => $oField));
                if(null !== $oFieldValue) {
                    $oForm->get('custom__' . $oField->getKey())->setData($oFieldValue->getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

Then, in your controller action which handles the request of the submitted form:

```
// Handle custom user fields
foreach($oForm->all() as $sKey => $oFormData)
{
    if(strstr($sKey, 'custom__'))
    {
        $sFieldKey = str_replace('custom__', '', $sKey);
        $oField = $oEm->getRepository('MyDBBundle:CustomUserField')->findOneBy(array('key' => $sFieldKey));
        /** @var CustomUserFieldValue $oFieldValue */
        $oFieldValue = $oEm->getRepository('MyDBBundle:CustomUserFieldValue')->findOneBy(array('user' => $oEntity, 'field' => $oField));
        if($oFieldValue === null)
        {
            $oFieldValue = new CustomUserFieldValue();
            $oFieldValue->setUser($oEntity);
            $oFieldValue->setField($oField);
        }
        $oFieldValue->setValue($oFormData->getData());
        $oEm->persist($oFieldValue);
    }
}
```

(Assuming that there is both a "field" property and a "key" in the CustomUserField entity; **key** is a unique, spaceless identifier for your field and **field** is the human friendly and readable field label.)

This works so hope it can be helpful. However, wondering if someone has a better solution. :)